# Advice on narrow CNC angles

Tags: router-bit, milling, cnc

I’d like to cut this with a CNC machine:

[image]

It will slot into another piece. As you can’t really create internal 90 degree angles with CNC the other piece has 10mm fillets as does this piece  - but it occurred to me that also the blue lines I’ve highlighted might arguably need filleting also, is that correct?

Comment: What does the opposing piece look like exactly? Does it have opposing fillets (scoops?)?

Comment: Yes, essentially the inverse of this, for a lattice on a staircase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming by CNC machine, you mean a router.

The blue line section that is horizontal will be a regular 90 degree cut.  The sections of the blue line that are on the curves will have an increasing large fillet as it approaches the bottom of the cut, unless you have a 4th axis on your CNC to rotate the item.  The cuts on the curves will also not be smooth without a 4th axis.

Comment: Thanks, yes that makes sense, thanks for explaining. Also, yes, the second time I said CNC I should have said CNC router :-)